# application custom log levels not working in wildfly22

Tags: jboss, log4j

Application custom log levels working in WebSphere Application Server however same code & logic not working in wildfly22 server. Inbuilt log levels like debug, error working fine. Is there any dependencies or issue with wildfly server?
we are using log4j1.8 api in both servers. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you excluding log4j from your deployment? I'm not sure what log4j 1.8 is BTW. That version does not exist to my knowledge.

Comment: I meant we are using jakarta-log4j-1.2.8 jar in our project. we have issue with custom log for our application log not the server log.

Comment: You likely need to exclude the servers version of log4j. I'd also suggest upgrade log4j as there are CVEs in that version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, our application custom logs worked for log4j-1.2.8.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, our application custom logs worked for log4j-1.2.8 after excluding the server version of log4j in deployment-structure.xml. We are remediating the log4j CVE. For that we are upgrading to log4j2.x and we are using three jars log4j-1.2-api-2.17.0, log4j-api-2.17.0 and log4j-1.2-core-2.17.0. but logs are  again not working in both wildfly as well as WebSphere Application Server. Please advise.

Comment: For WildFly you might have to exclude the `org.apache.logging.log4j.api` module or just don't include log4j-core and it will log to the `server.log`. It depends on your logging requirements.

Comment: It did not work after excluding org.apache.logging.log4j.api module as well as  log4j-core . We are using log4j1.properties file. Do we need to use log4j2 properties/xml file in this scenario?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use log4j2 you have to use a log4j2 configuration file.